# Using category slug in add_rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, actions, rewrite-rules

I'm using this function ro rewrite URLs:

```
function archive_rewrite_rules(){
add_rewrite_rule(
    'inspiracao/([^/]*)/([0-9]{4})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=post&cat=$matches[1]&year=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'archive_rewrite_rules' );
```

But is possible to use category slug instead category id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
category_name=$matches[1]
```

instead of

```
cat=$matches[1]
```

Generally speaking, you can use any built-in public query variable and custom ones, after some additional work, see the [`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) codex entry for more information.